# How to diable fast boot from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, hibernate

I am using HP 15-ac028TX Laptop.
I have dual  boot for Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. 3 days before when I shut down my Windows it shut immediately. When I boot it again computer was working but there was no display (i.e black screen).

I tried removing the battery and pressing the power button for 60 second method for many times but it didn't work. 
But after approx 21 hours when I boot it again it worked. I thought it was a temporary problem. But after some time when I restart again the same problem persists. It took another 27 hours to boot it again. 
I read on internet that it may be because of fast boot and hibernation.
So I want to diable fast boot and hibernation from Ubuntu without restarting. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: you have to do it from windows. but your problem sounds like a failing HDD

Comment: i can't risk restarting again , is there is any way to do it from ubuntu

Comment: nope, Windows operation can only be changed from windows

Comment: Fast Boot is an UEFI setting, so you need to reboot and get into UEFI. Fast Boot has UEFI assume you have made no hardware or configuration settings, so it just jumps immediately to booting default system without rescanning hardware. It is usually too quick to let you press any keys. Fast start up is a Windows hibernation setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I want to disable fast boot and hibernation from Ubuntu without restarting. Is there any way to do it??

No.

But I doubt your problem is with fast booting and hibernation. I would believe this is hardware starting to fail so even if you could change it from within Ubuntu then you might still end up with a not-booting system.

So start making a backup if you do not have one before rebooting. Your 1st concern should be your own data.